# How to write music notes with LaTeX

Tags: music, musixtex, pmx

[image]

How to write this musician notes with LaTeX?

Please give me some examples and instructions.

Comment: This could help: https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-write-music-with-latex/

Comment: Use Lilypond (lilypond.org) if you only want the score and Lilypond-book in combination with LaTeX if you want text and music in the same document